# Не кликабелен баннер Admob в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, admob, плагин

Создал проект для Android, взял для размещения рекламы самый стандартный Admob plugin для unity.
В итоге: Приложение работает прекрасно, реклама показывется, но при клике на баннер ничего не происходит. Кто знает, как исправить?

Comment: я не знаком со связкой Android + Unity, но логика подсказывает, что вам нужно указать некий TargetUrl для AdMob контрола.

Comment: Я полностью согласен, но он же меняется при смене рекламы, т.е. сейчас мне показывают рекламу собачек, а через 60 секунд будут показывать рекламу кошек, они же не на один url идут.

Comment: @Expert есть приложение на Android, созданное на движке Unity3D.
При создании приложения использовал плагин Admob для размещения рекламы в приложении в виде баннера, в итоге:
Приложение работает стабильно, реклама показывается, но нельзя на неё кликнуть и перейти по url на сам рекламируемый продукт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён, просто попался плохой Admob Plugin с недостающими файлами, всем спасибо за участие, скачать нормальный плагин для решения этого вопроса можно по ссылке:
https://github.com/guillermocalvo/admob-unity-plugin/tree/master/Releases